# biblatex: how to abbreviate forenames

Tags: biblatex, formatting

I have several full names in my rather large bibiography. Since I do not want to change all these I'd like to have the forename shortened to an initial.

So "Lieschen Mueller" should get "Mueller L.".

I use the standard `authoryear` style.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the package option `firstinits=true`. (I answered this, among other things, in [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles).)